The JSON property name for 'StatusCode' collides with another property
How can I support case-sensitive property names in System.Text.Json in .NET?
[JsonPropertyName("statusCode")]
public string? StatusCode { get; set; }

[JsonPropertyName("StatusCode")]
public string? AbcApiStatusCode { get; set; }

I have tried to set case sensitivity as well :
public static JsonSerializerOptions Default => new()
{
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = false,
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
};

But still getting this error :

The JSON property name for 'StatusCode' collides with another property.


Shouldn't be PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,?

@Steve: No, the OP wants it to be case sensitive.

Please could you provide a [mcve]? It's a lot easier to experiment when we've got a minimal example that we know is the same as the one you're using. (At the moment we don't have any context for when you're seeing this error, for a start...)

@JonSkeet Sharing the complete context is not possible due to authorized APIs,  string response = "{\"statusCode\":\"200\",\"StatusCode\":\"200\"}";    var responseDemo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseDemo>(response);  Although I hv tried similar thing in a different console application where I have given same property names as I put in the question, and tried to de serialize it with System.Text.Json,  it works fine with that

"Sharing the complete context is not possible due to authorized APIs" - you don't need to make any network requests to provide a [mcve]. The kind of hard-coded JSON you included in your comment should be in your question, along with how you're using the JsonSerializerOptions. All I'm looking for is a 20 line console app that demonstrates the problem, without me having to guess at anything. I should be able to copy, paste, compile and run. No network requests, no extra baggage - just a minimal example. I don't know what you mean by "Although I hv tried similar thing, it works fine with that"

I cannot reproduce your problem in .NET 8.  If I create a ResponseDemo model with the two properties, I can deserialize and re-serialize successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/e4YMjK.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as indicated in [ask].  Thanks!

As stated in the documentation page Web defaults for JsonSerializerOptions: The following options have different defaults for web apps: PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true  If you are binding your model in some ASP.NET Core endpoint, you must explicitly set PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false in AddJsonOptions(), because ASP.NET Core will have set it to true by default.

In my Program.cs :
I changed the code from :
builder.Services.AddControllers();

To :
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false);

Courtesy of this original question
